# DJANGO ListView returns HTTPResponse, but I need a json

Tags: json, django, serialization

I am having a problem around the Class Based Views in Django. I need to create JSON responses, instead of rendering to a template.

```
class AllItem(ListView):
    model = MyModel
    context_object_name = 'items'
    template_name = 'mymodel/index.html'
```

I also have a serializer class

```
class SpendingConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialier):
    class Meta:
        model = SpendingConfig
        fields = ('record_date', 'amount', 'name')
```

Does anyone know how to connect them?

Thanks
Z.

Comment: You should work with a `ListAPIView`. It also is odd that you specify a `template_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a `ListAPIView` and specify your `SpendingConfigSerializer` as serializer:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = SpendingConfig.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SpendingConfigSerializer
```